# $\frac{2n\choose n}{n+2}\not\in\mathbb N$ and $n\neq3k+1$ and $n\neq4k+2$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, catalan-numbers

> Are there any natural numbers $n\not\equiv1\bmod3$, **and** $n\not\equiv2\bmod4$, so that $~\dfrac{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}{n+2}\not\in\mathbb N$ ?

Since $C_n=\dfrac{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}{n+1}\in\mathbb N$ for all *n*, this is equivalent to asking whether there are any **Catalan**

numbers **not** divisible by $n+2$, with *n* **neither** of the form $3k+1$, **nor** of the form  $4k+2$.

---

Inspired by the afore-mentioned [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), I began investigating integers with the property

that $~\dfrac{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}{n+2}\in\mathbb N$, and then soon afterwards arrived at the conclusion that there were too many of

them for such a quest to be even remotely interesting, so I negated the above property, and, after a

rather short while, I immediately started noticing that the new results were either of the form $n=$

$=3k+1$, or of the form $n=4k+2$. Updating the search parameters so as to eliminate these two

classes as well, I eventually came to the realization that there were no solutions for $n\le10^5$.

Comment: The numbers $n$ have the form $12k$, $12k+3$, $12k+5$, $12k+8$, $12k+9$ or $12k+11$.

Comment: See also [OEIS A$094453$](https://oeis.org/A094453).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Catalan Numbers are $${2n\choose n}-{2n\choose n+1}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}(n+1-n)$$
Try a similar thing for these numbers: 
$$A{2n\choose n}+B{2n\choose n+1}+C{2n\choose n+2}\\
=\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+2)!}\left[A(n+2)(n+1)+Bn(n+2)+Cn(n-1)\right]\\
A+B+C=0,3A+2B-C=1,2A=1\\
A=1/2,B=-1/3,C=-1/6\\
D_n=\frac1{n+2}{2n\choose n}=\frac12{2n\choose n}-\frac13{2n\choose n+1}-\frac16{2n\choose n+2}\\
=\frac12{2n\choose n}-\frac13\left[{2n\choose n+1}-{2n\choose n+2}\right]-\frac12{2n\choose n+2}$$
${2n\choose n}=2{2n-1\choose n}$ so the first term is an integer.
$$(n-1)\left[{2n\choose n+1}-{2n\choose n+2}\right]=\frac{3(2n)!}{(n-2)!(n+2)!}
$$
which is a multiple of $3$, so when you divide by $n-1$ it is still a multiple of $3$ unless $n=1\mod 3$.
That leaves 
$$\frac12{2n\choose n+2}=\frac n{n+2}{2n-1\choose n+1}$$ 
which only has an extra 2 in the denominator  if $n=2\mod 4$.

Comment: It seems so simple in retrospect...